# How to align div vertically in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to align the card into center vertically

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container" style="width: 100%;height: 100vh">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The container has height: 100vh; and width:100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make container as `flex` and add
`align-items-center` to center items vertically

to make sure that the row will remains full width add: `w-100` class to the row

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 100%;height: 100vh">
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it means it's apply to all tags that container contain this is wrong can you justify

Answer (score 1):

Try using bootstrap class names: `d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center` inside your `container` div class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1>hello</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: already tried this and doesn't work. It works horizontally but vertically no

Comment: I've updated my answer check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `d-flex align-items-center` class in Bootstrap

Your h1 have a `margin-bottom` so it can show not align  vertically it remove by add `mb-0` to `h1`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container d-flex align-items-center" style="width: 100%;height: 100vh">
  <div class="row w-100">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <h1 class="mb-0">hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Bogdan Paul please check this

Answer (score 0):

you want to vertically align a  element in the center or middle, you can simply apply the class `align-items-center` on the containing element.

Comment: It doesn't work I don't know why, you mean to add align-items-center to that div that has col-md-6?

Comment: no  add this to row